# FunScript querySelector null result

Tags: f#, funscript

I want to use `document.querySelector` method to get html node. In Js I can receive `null` as a result. But in F# the result type is `Element` and it's neither nullable nor optional and it's not clear how to check it for `null`. How can I handle the situation when `querySelector` doesn't match any DOM node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true the F# code assumes Element is not nullable. You can trick the compiler to think otherwise in several ways. Probably the easiest one is to box the value like this:

```
let el = Globals.document.querySelector(".myclass")
if (box el) = null
then doSomething()
else doSomethingElse()`
```

`box` will be ignored when generating the JS code, so there's no performance penalty in doing this.